# Even the python code seems correct but attribute error occur, no text scraped

Tags: object, web-scraping, attributes, attributeerror, findall

When I was using BeautifulSoup to scrape listing product name and price, the similar code worked on other website. But when running in this website, soup.findAll attributes are there but no text scraped, AttributeError occurred. Is anyone can help to take look the code and website inspect?

I checked and ran many times, the same issue remained

Codes are here:

```
url = 'https://shopee.co.id/Handphone-Aksesoris-cat.40'
re = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(str(re.status_code))
soup = BeautifulSoup(re.text, "html.parser")
for el in soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "collection-card_collecton-title"}):
    name = el.get.text()
    print(name)
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an `i` in the class name. However, content is dynamically loaded from API call (which is why you can't find it in your call where js doesn't run and so this next call to update DOM doesn't occur); you can find in network tab. It returns json.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://shopee.co.id/api/v2/custom_collection/get?category_id=40&platform=0').json()
titles = [i['collection_title'] for i in r['collections'][0]['list_popular_collection']]
print(titles)
```

---

[image]

---

**Prices as well:**

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://shopee.co.id/api/v2/custom_collection/get?category_id=40&platform=0').json()
titles,prices =zip(*[(i['collection_title'], i['price']) for i in r['collections'][0]['list_popular_collection']])
print(titles,prices)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Yes, I did miss i when I posted in here. The code I ran has i in it. You are right. I'll try your codes, to see I can get name and similarly its price. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you! I tried and got both  titles and price. It is a wonderful help, I was trying over a day. So I am new to this site, I tried. I am so fortunate got so quick response and guidance from you.

Comment: for i in range(1,5): 
  
    download_url = 'https://shopee.co.id/Hot-Deals-Elektronik-Murah-30-Ags-5-Sep-col.255624?freeShipping=false&page='+str(i-1)+'&sortBy=pop'
    print(download_url, sep='\n') 

    for el in soup.findAll('class', attrs={"data-sqe": "name"}):

        name1 = el.text
        name2 = name1.find("class").text
        print(name2,',',end="")
    print()

     
    for el in soup.findAll('span', attrs={"class": "_341bF0"}):
        name2 = el.get_text()
        print(name2,',',end="")
        
   How to change those accordingly to your API web address?

Comment: I was able to find the get from network tab. However for the vast product listing and price that posted in my last comment, no related get - API site information was found.

Comment: really appreciate if you could help the second part.

Comment: Will have a look

Comment: Thanks. It is really kind of you.

Comment: you are selecting from the top ribbon. There are no changes to this as you loop results pages.

Comment: But with the lower ribbon gave no results as well. I had similar one, it worked. It may be API like you from Network Tab but I could not find the related get API from the network tab.